# How to stop implicit conversion to virtual function

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

```
struct A{
    virtual void fun(){cout<<"A";}
};
struct B:public A{
    void fun(){cout<<"B";}
};
struct C:public B{
    void fun(){cout<<"C";}
};
int main() 
{
    C c;B b1;   
    A *a=&b1;
    a->fun(); //1
    B *b=&c;
    b->fun(); //2
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code B::fun() is getting converted to virtual function implicitly as I have made A::fun() virtual. Can I stop this conversion?

If not possible what are the alternatives to make the above code print "BB" ?

Comment: If you didn't want a virtual function... why did you make it virtual in the base class in the first place?

Comment: I want A::fun() to be virtual

Comment: @banarun if you don't want it to act like a virtual function, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual function is virtual in all derived classes. There is no way to prevent this.

> (§10.3/2 C++11) If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides Base::vf. For convenience we say that any virtual function overrides itself.

However, if you'd like to use the function that corresponds to the *static*, rather than the *dynamic*, type of a pointer (i.e., in your example, `B::fun` instead of `C::fun`, given that the pointer is declared as `B*`), then you can, at least in C++11, use the alias definition below to get access to the static (=compile-time) type:

```
template <typename Ptr>
using static_type = typename std::remove_pointer<Ptr>::type;
```

This is how you'd use this in `main()` (or anywhere else):

```
int main() 
{
  C c; B b1;   

  A *a = &b1;
  a->fun();

  B *b = &c;

  /* This will output 'B': */    
  b->static_type<decltype(b)>::fun();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you do not want your derived classes to override the function then there is no reason why you should mark it `virtual` in base class. The very basis of marking a function `virtual` is to have polymorphic behavior through derived class function overidding.

**Good Read:**
[When to mark a function in C++ as a virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298041/when-to-mark-a-function-in-c-as-a-virtual)

- If you want your code to guard you against accidental overidding in derived classes.You can use the **[final specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)** in C++11.

Comment: No I actually want the base class to be virtual, but I don't want derived class to be virtual.

Comment: Doesn't that prevent overriding a function from the base class, rather than allowing you to override with a non-`virtual` function?

Comment: @banarun That defeats the purpose entirely, if only the base class is "virtual" then it isn't virtual.

Comment: @banarun: If you do not have a overidding behavior in derived class then Why would you want to mark the base class function to be `virtual`? It only makes sense if you have an overidding behavior in derived class.

Comment: I want base Class to be overridden by derived Class. But I don't want derived class to be overridden by another class that is derived from it.

Comment: @banarun then you use `final` in the first derived class.

Comment: @banarun: You don't override classes. You override functions in those classes. overriding makes sense when you have polymorphic(*different*) behavior for a function with same name across base and derived class.Now if you don't need that there is no need of overriding at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to explicitly call a function in a specific class you can use a fully qualified name.

```
b->A::fun();
```

This will call the version of `fun()` belonging to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The following achieves the observable behaviour you're asking for.  In `A`, non-`virtual` `fun()` run virtual `fun_()` so the behaviour can be customised in `B`, but anyone calling `fun()` on a derived class will only see the non-polymorphic version.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    void fun(){fun_();}
  private:
    virtual void fun_() { cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B:public A{
    void fun(){cout<<"B\n";}
  private:
    virtual void fun_() final { fun(); }
};

struct C:public B{
    void fun(){cout<<"C\n";}
};

int main()
{
    C c;B b1;
    A *a=&b1;
    a->fun(); //1
    B *b=&c;
    b->fun(); //2
    c.fun();    // notice that this outputs "C" which I think is what you want
}
```

If using C++03, you can simply leave out the "final" keyword - it's only there to guard against further unwanted overrides of the virtual behaviour in `B`-derived classes such as `C`.

(You might find it interesting to contrast this with the "Nonvirtual Interface pattern" - see C++ Coding Standards by Sutter and Alexandrescu, point 39)

**Discussion**

`A` having `fun` virtual implies that overriding it in derived classes is a necessary customisation ability for derived classes, but at some point in the derivation hierarchy the choice of implementation behaviours might have narrowed down to 1 and providing a `final` implementation's not unreasonable.

My real concern is that you *hide* `A`/`B`'s `fun()` with `C::fun`... that's troubling as if they do different things then your code could be very hard to reason about or debug.  `B`'s decision to finalise the virtual function implies certainty that there's no need for such further customisation.  Code working from `A*`/`A&`/`B*`/`B&` will do one thing, while wherever a `C` object's type is statically known, the behaviour may differ.  Templated code is one place where `C::fun` may easily be called without the template author or user being very conscious of it.  To assess whether this is a genuine hazard for you, it would help to know what the functional purpose of "fun" is and how implementation might differ between `A`, `B` and `C`....

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the function in B like this

```
void fun(int ignored=0);
```

it will become an overload which will not take part in resolving virtual calls. Beware that calling `a->fun()` will call `A::fun()` though even if `a` actually refers to a `B`, so **I would strongly advise against this approach** as it makes things even more confusing than necessary.

Question is: What exactly is it that you want to achieve or avoid? Knowing that, people here could suggest a better approach.